# populate label when load jquery popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Will be displaying a jquery popup many times through out my project. I would like to populate the label inside the div with a different message each time so for eg...

```
var popUpMessageSave = "You have successfully saved."; 
loadPopUp(popUpMessageSave);

var popUpMessageFail = "You have failed to save."; 
loadPopUp(popUpMessageFail);
```

not sure how to populate the label each time??

```
  <div style="display: none;">
        <div id="saveDialogSingleFeature" title="Save Complete">
            <input type="text" title="Name" value=""/>
            <label></label>
        </div>
    </div>

function loadPopUp(popUpMessage) {

    $("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog({
        width: "auto",
        height: "auto",
        position: { my: "top", at: "bottom", of: $("header") },
        show: { effect: "slideDown" },
        hide: true,
        closeOnEscape: true

    }).parent().appendTo("form:first");

    //clear label and add new 
    $('input:text').next('label').html("");
    $(this).next('label').html(popUpMessage);


    setTimeout(function () {
            $("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog('close')
            }, 5000);
}
```

**UPDATE**
Added an ID to the DIV and add empty and append to the loadPopUpMessage()

```
$("#popUpLabel").empty();
 $("#popUpLabel").append("some Text");

<input type="text" id="popUpLabel" value=""/>
```

Comment: on what conditions do you want to show the messages? On any click action or open action of the popup?

Comment: Where do you call the popup, from code behind? Secondly your label needs an ID, so that your jQuery can refer to it.

Comment: I always want to show a message, but a differnt one each time, so when I call loadPopUp(popUpMessage), I can set the text of popupMessage to the relevent text I need

Comment: Purely based on what you've posted, you may try replacing the 2 lines just below `//clear label and add new` with `$('input:text').next('label').text(popUpMessage)`. And what does `$(this)` refer to (most probably `undefined`)?

Comment: I call the popup from a JS page..please see updae

Comment: As @KaustavBanerjee asked, what condition, what events you are showing pop-up or calling your `loadPopUpMessage`??